# path of installation

Tags: java, path, installation

I have a problem. Im doing an installer for my program, but how I tell to class which is the path of installation

new FileInputStream("**pathInstallation**/DESTest.txt")

Greetings

Comment: Can you be clearer as to what you are doing? (Environment, Platform, Installer) If you want to just load a file from the installation directory I would stick it on the classpath and load it that way.

Comment: how I stick the path on the classpath?

Answer (score 3):

> how I stick the path on the classpath?

Use [`Class.getResource`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) methods.

The resource is any file which is located next to your compiled .class file. Pass the name of the file (without the path) to one of these methods and read its content.